# How to use ILIKE in PySpark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-like

I have a query

```sql
select * from 
table 
where (primary_product NOT IN ('No Technical Enforcement')
   or group_name ilike ('%stove%'))
```

I want to convert the same query into PySpark SQL, but I am not able to do the same as I don't know the substitute of **ILIKE**.

Answer (score 1):

[**`ilike`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.ilike.html#pyspark.sql.Column.ilike) was only added in Spark 3.3 (released 2022 June 16) - both, in SQL and PySpark.

You use it in the same way as `like` or `rlike`.

Example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Tom', 80), ('Alice', None)], ["name", "height"])
# +-----+------+
# | name|height|
# +-----+------+
# |  Tom|    80|
# |Alice|  null|
# +-----+------+

df = df.filter(df.name.ilike('%Ice'))
# +-----+------+
# | name|height|
# +-----+------+
# |Alice|  null|
# +-----+------+
```

Comment: so basically we need to create a DataFrame , I tried using it in pyspark sql and it didn't work

Comment: Well, there;s no such thing as pyspark sql. You either do it in pyspark (python), or you do it in Spark SQL. In Spark SQL you don't have dataframes, you have tables. But in PySpark, you have dataframes. Which one do you work with? Do you mind explaining more in detail in your question? (you would need to edit the question).

Answer (score 0):

ILIKE does exist in Spark SQL. [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#ilike) you can find the documentation.

Example:

```
SELECT ilike('Spark', '_Park');
```

Returns true.

Comment: I am not able to understand what are you trying to state here. Also can you tell us or guide for a proper solution for the same . That would be helpful

Comment: The solution is, that you don't have to replace ILIKE, since the Spark SQL Dialect supports that function.

Comment: what will be the output then? how do I write it? Also ILike is for case sensitive , my data looks like group_name = 'Stove Upfront EasyBuy Kibwezi'.

Comment: I linked you the documentation, you should be able to deduct the information you need from there. In addition, your question was titled "How to replace ILIKE" and this question should be answered, you don't need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

> Import col from sql functions in pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

> like filter condition

```
df.filter(col("group_name").like("%stove%")).show()
```

> OR

```
spark.sql("select * from table where group_name like '%stove%'").show()
```

Comment: but how will you substitute ILIKE with like because group_name = 'Stove Upfront EasyBuy Kibwezi'. So how will you filter for something which is case sensitive . The whole purpose of using ILIKE was to get the case sensitive into consideration

Comment: @bigDataArtist Ilike is postgre sql version of case insensitive. in PySpark like is case insensitive.

Comment: ,Sure . So let me correct you its SQL but I use the one with Pyspark implementation and not the Scala.